# Error en navegación

Tags: flutter, dart

Al parecer sale error cuando quiero navegar de una ventana a otra, me pide agregar el `currentIndex`, en esta situación, no sé cómo se colocaría para que permita navegar.
Estaba tratando de hacer una barra de navegación pero no sé la solución ante esta situación.

```
content: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Iniciar"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageHome()));
        },
      ),
```

Esta es la ventana a la que quiero navegar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class pageHome extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function currentIndex;
  const pageHome({Key? key, required this.currentIndex}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _pageHomeState createState() => _pageHomeState();
}

class _pageHomeState extends State<pageHome> {
  int index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int i) {
          setState(() {
            index = i;
            widget.currentIndex(i);
          });
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.purple,
        iconSize: 25.0,
        selectedFontSize: 14.0,
        unselectedFontSize: 12.0,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined), label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined), label: 'Perfil'),
        ]);
  }
}
```

*Error de la consola:*

```
Error: Required named parameter 'currentIndex' must be provided.
quiz.dart:162
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageHome()));
                                                                       ^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
pagehome.dart:5
  const pageHome({Key? key, required this.currentIndex}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: en el pageHome tienes un parametro obligatorio denominado "currentIndex" que lo asignas como función, para qué te sirve esta función?

Comment: @JonathanPerez
Se supone que trataba de crear una barra de navegación y que cuando se aprete el botón esta llame  a la pagina que deseo mostrar y el currentIndex me permite realizar esto, entonces estaba tratando de vincular que después de las pantallas de registro aparezca esta barra de navegación.

Comment: pero no creo que sea necesario ese parámetro en el homePage, eso es lo que te está dando el error

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo desde el login quieres enviar una función con el index del `bottomNavigationBar`, no le encuentro mucho sentido porque dentro del `pageHome` tienes creada una variable `index` que con este manejarias la posición de cada elemento de la barra de navegación, el error sucede porque en el constructor de `pageHome` estás asignando un parámetro obligatorio y como en la pagina del login lo estás llamando sin asignarle algún parámetro entonces te bota el error, como te digo, creo que es innecesario, modificando tu código quedaría así:

```
class pageHome extends StatefulWidget {
      //comentamos esta línea que es en la que se asigna el parámetro
      //final Function currentIndex;
      //y aquí en el constructor comentamos el parámetro
      const pageHome({Key? key, /*required this.currentIndex*/}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _pageHomeState createState() => _pageHomeState();
    }
    
    class _pageHomeState extends State<pageHome> {
      //esta es la variable que debería hacer siempre el cambió de indice de la barra de navegación.
      int index = 0;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: index,
            onTap: (int i) {
              setState(() {
                index = i;
                //esta línea también estaría de más
                //widget.currentIndex(i);
              });
            },
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.purple,
            iconSize: 25.0,
            selectedFontSize: 14.0,
            unselectedFontSize: 12.0,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.assessment_outlined), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined), label: 'Perfil'),
            ]);
      }
    }
```

Si te sale algún otro error, dejame un comentario para poder ayudarte, pero en un principio esto debería solucionar ese error.